# Titanium studio display error events.js

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

I installed titanium studio on windows xp

When trying to launch an application "hello world" in the tablet (recognizing) titanium shows an error in evets, js

Looking online seems to be the problem of environment variables. However, I can not get it to work.

Someone can help me?

thanks

My path environment variables:

```
%CLASSPATH%;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;C:\Archivos de programa\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\bin;C:\apache-ant-1.7.1\bin;C:\Documents and Settings\gcid\Escritorio\eclipsePhonegapp\sdk\tools;C:\android-sdk\tools;C:\android-sdk\platform-tools;C:\Archivos de programa\Git\cmd;C:\Archivos de programa\nodejs\;C:\Archivos de programa\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin;C:\Archivos de programa\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin;
```

The error:

```
Titanium Command-Line Interface, CLI version 3.2.1, Titanium SDK version 3.2.1.GA
Copyright (c) 2012-2014, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
Please report bugs to http://jira.appcelerator.org/
[INFO] :   Found Titanium plugin id=ti.alloy version=1.0 
[INFO] :   Deploy type: test
[INFO] :   Building for target: device
[INFO] :   Building for device: C16903012641A2E
[INFO] :   Targeting Android SDK: 16
[INFO] :   Building for the following architectures: armeabi, armeabi-v7a, x86
[INFO] :   Signing with keystore: C:\Documents and Settings\gcid\Datos de programa\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.1.GA\android\dev_keystore (tidev)
[INFO] :   Debugging disabled
[INFO] :   Profiler disabled
[INFO] :   Forcing rebuild: C:\Documents and Settings\gcid\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\pruebas\build\android\build-manifest.json does not exist
[INFO] :   Found Alloy app in C:\Documents and Settings\gcid\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\pruebas\app
[INFO] :   Executing Alloy compile: alloy.cmd compile C:\Documents and Settings\gcid\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\pruebas\app --config platform=android,version=0,simtype=none,devicefamily=none,deploytype=test
[INFO] :   ----- MVC GENERATION -----
[INFO] :   [global style] loading from cache...
[INFO] :   [index.xml] view processing...
[INFO] :     style:      "index.tss"
[INFO] :     view:       "index.xml"
[INFO] :     controller: "index.js"
[INFO] :     created:    "Resources\android\alloy\controllers\index.js"
[INFO] :     created:     "Resources\android\alloy\styles\index.js"
[INFO] :   
[INFO] :   [app.js] using cached app.js...
[INFO] :   
[INFO] :   ----- OPTIMIZING -----
[INFO] :   - android\alloy.js
[INFO] :   - android\alloy\sync\localStorage.js
[INFO] :   - android\alloy\sync\properties.js
[INFO] :   - android\alloy\sync\sql.js
[INFO] :   
[INFO] :   Alloy compiled in 0.51163s
[INFO] :   Alloy compiler completed successfully
[INFO] :   Processing JavaScript files
[INFO] :   Encrypting JavaScript files: C:\Documents and Settings\gcid\Datos de programa\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.1.GA\android\titanium_prep.win32.exe "com.bilbomatica.pruebas" "C:\Documents and Settings\gcid\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\pruebas\build\android\assets" "app.js" "alloy/backbone.js" "alloy/CFG.js" "alloy/constants.js" "alloy/controllers/BaseController.js" "alloy/controllers/index.js" "alloy/styles/index.js" "alloy/sync/localStorage.js" "alloy/sync/properties.js" "alloy/sync/sql.js" "alloy/underscore.js" "alloy/widget.js" "alloy.js" "_app_props_.json"
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn Unknown system errno 193
    at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:771:34)
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 8
```

Comment: did you found out why this is happening ?